# How to configure nHibernate for many-many mapping?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, c#-4.0, many-to-many

Using nHibernate 3.2, C# 4.0, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

I have two business entities - `Broker` and `Market`. They are stored in the `brokers` and `markets` tables respectively. I also have `brokerMarkets` table with one extra column called `MinIncrement`. There's a many-many relationship between Broker and Market, but **only when I want to store a MinIncrement** value (i.e. it's optional). My classes look like this:

```
public class Market : BusinessBase
{
    public Market() {}

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Symbol { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Broker : BusinessBase
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class BrokerMarket : Market
{
    public BrokerMarket() { }

    public virtual Broker Broker {get; set;}
    public virtual decimal MinIncrement { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping files look like this:
Market.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="MooDB"
                   namespace="MooDB.BusinessLayer">

    <class name="MooDB.BusinessLayer.Market,MooDB" table="markets">
        <id name="Id" column="marketId" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>           
        <version name="Version" column="version" type="integer" unsaved-value="0" />
        <property name="Symbol" column="symbol" type="String" length="10" not-null="true" />
        <property name="Description" column="description" type="String" length="30" not-null="true" />

        <set name="Brokers" generic="true" table="brokerMarkets">
            <key column="marketId" />
            <many-to-many column="brokerId" class="MooDB.BusinessLayer.Broker,MooDB" />            
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Broker.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="MooDB"
                   namespace="MooDB.BusinessLayer">

    <class name="MooDB.BusinessLayer.Broker,MooDB" table="brokers">
        <id name="Id" column="brokerId" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <version name="Version" column="version" type="integer" unsaved-value="0" />
        <property name="Name" column="broker" type="String" length="50" not-null="true" />
        <property name="IsActive" column="isActive" type="bool" not-null="true" />
        <property name="IsDefault" column="isDefault" type="bool" not-null="true" />

        <set name="Markets" generic="true" table="brokerMarkets">
            <key column="brokerId" />
            <many-to-many column="marketId" class="MooDB.BusinessLayer.Market,MooDB" />
        </set>

        <set name="Accounts" table="accounts" generic="true" inverse="true">
            <key column="brokerId" />
            <one-to-many class="MooDB.BusinessLayer.Account,MooDB" />
        </set>
    </class>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In my data access layer I have a method to add a BrokerMarket:

```
public void AddBrokerMarket(BrokerMarket bm)
{
    using (ITransaction tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            _session.Save(bm);
            _session.Flush();
            tx.Commit();
        }
        catch (HibernateException)
        {
            tx.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

In my unit test I try and add a BrokerMarket like this:

```
[Test]
public void CanAddBrokerMarket()
{
    Broker broker = _provider.GetBrokerById(1);
    Market market = _provider.GetMarketById(2);
    var brokerMarket = new BrokerMarket { Broker = broker, Description = market.Description, Symbol = market.Symbol, MinIncrement = 0.01M };
    _provider.AddBrokerMarket(brokerMarket);
}
```

When I run the test I get this error:

> Running the tests. Test
>   'MooDBTests/MooDB/Tests/DataLayerTests/CanAddBrokerMarket' failed:
>     Message     NHibernate.MappingException : No persister for:
>   MooDB.BusinessLayer.BrokerMarket      Stack Trace     at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String
>   entityName)   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.GetEntityPersister(String
>   entityName, Object obj)   at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object
>   entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source,
>   Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
>     NHibernateDataProvider.cs(91,0): at
>   MooDB.DataLayer.NHibernateDataProvider.AddBrokerMarket(BrokerMarket
>   bm)   DataLayerTests.cs(81,0): at
>   MooDB.Tests.DataLayerTests.CanAddBrokerMarket()

I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Do I need to add a `Broker` collection in the `Market` class and a `Market` collection in the `Broker` class? I did try that but I get the same error, and I think I'm missing something conceptually somewhere.

**UPDATE**

I have implemented the following changes:
Market.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="MooDB"
                   namespace="MooDB.BusinessLayer">

    <class name="MooDB.BusinessLayer.Market,MooDB" table="markets">
        <id name="Id" column="marketId" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>           
        <version name="Version" column="version" type="integer" unsaved-value="0" />
        <property name="Symbol" column="symbol" type="String" length="10" not-null="true" />
        <property name="Description" column="description" type="String" length="30" not-null="true" />
      <map name="BrokerMarkets" table="brokerMarkets" lazy="true" cascade="none">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <key column="marketId" />
        <index column="brokerId" type="Int32" />
        <composite-element class="MooDB.BusinessLayer.BrokerMarket,MooDB">
          <parent name="Market"/>
          <property name="MinIncrement" column="minIncrement" type="decimal" />
          <many-to-one name="Broker" class="MooDB.BusinessLayer.Broker,MooDB" column="brokerId" />
        </composite-element>        
      </map>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Broker.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="MooDB"
                   namespace="MooDB.BusinessLayer">

    <class name="MooDB.BusinessLayer.Broker,MooDB" table="brokers">
        <id name="Id" column="brokerId" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <version name="Version" column="version" type="integer" unsaved-value="0" />
        <property name="Name" column="broker" type="String" length="50" not-null="true" />
        <property name="IsActive" column="isActive" type="bool" not-null="true" />
        <property name="IsDefault" column="isDefault" type="bool" not-null="true" />

        <set name="Accounts" table="accounts" generic="true" inverse="true">
            <key column="brokerId" />
            <one-to-many class="MooDB.BusinessLayer.Account,MooDB" />
        </set>
    </class>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

`Market` class:

```
public class Market : BusinessBase
{
    public Market() {}

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Symbol { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<BrokerMarket> BrokerMarkets { get; set; } //added this line
}
```

`BrokerMarket` class

```
public class BrokerMarket : Market
{
    public BrokerMarket() { }

    public virtual Broker Broker {get; set;}
    public virtual Market Market { get; set; } // added this line
    public virtual decimal MinIncrement { get; set; }
}
```

Everything else is unchanged. I run the unit test again and I get:

> Running the tests. Test
>   'MooDBTests/MooDB/Tests/DataLayerTests/CanAddBrokerMarket' failed:
>     Message     TestFixtureSetUp failed in DataLayerTests
>
> Test 'MooDBTests/MooDB/Tests/DataLayerTests' failed:  Message     SetUp :
>   NHibernate.MappingException : Repeated column in mapping for
>   collection: MooDB.BusinessLayer.Market.BrokerMarkets column: brokerId

**UPDATE 2**

If I remove

`<index column="brokerId" type="Int32" />`

from Market.hbm.xml I get this error when running the unit test:

> Running the tests. Test
>   'MooDBTests/MooDB/Tests/DataLayerTests/CanAddBrokerMarket' failed:
>     Message     TestFixtureSetUp failed in DataLayerTests
>
> Test 'MooDBTests/MooDB/Tests/DataLayerTests' failed:  Message     SetUp :
>   NHibernate.MappingException : MooDB.Mappings.Market.hbm.xml(17,10):
>   XML validation error: The element 'map' in namespace
>   'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element
>   'composite-element' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of
>   possible elements expected: 'map-key, composite-map-key,
>   map-key-many-to-many, index, composite-index, index-many-to-many,
>   index-many-to-any' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.       ---->
>   System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException : The element 'map' in
>   namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element
>   'composite-element' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of
>   possible elements expected: 'map-key, composite-map-key,
>   map-key-many-to-many, index, composite-index, index-many-to-many,
>   index-many-to-any' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.

Answer (score 0):

the error could be because you have not defined mapping for BrokerMarket Class, If you want to save broker market like the way you are doin will have to create BrokerMarket.hbm.xml. you may also have a look at using composite element here something like http://thesoftwaresimpleton.blogspot.com/2010/03/nhibernate-many-to-many-with-extra.html

Comment: I have updated my question with your suggestion, but I still can't get it working. Any further ideas?

Comment: remove broker id as index column

Comment: Use bag instead of map it allows duplicate

Comment: I never got this working so I went with two one-many mappings with a surrogate key in the association table `BrokerMarkets`