# Modeling many-to-many relationship in code

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, many-to-many

Using C#4.0

Following on from my question [How to configure nHibernate for many-many mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766096/how-to-configure-nhibernate-for-many-many-mapping) I'm getting confused and it may be because my class design is wrong.

A Market models a financial market. A Broker models a financial broker who can interact with many markets. A Market can interact with many Brokers. See the `Broker` and `Market` classes below.

```
public class Market
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Broker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public IList<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

I have an extra attribute in the many-to-many relationship called `MinIncrement` that is unique to a `Market` and a `Broker` combination.

What's the best way to model this? Do I need to create a third class or can I put `MinIncrement` in one of my existing classes? Should I create a third class and inherit from one of my existing ones? I'm not really sure how to model this in an OO way.

In my database it's easy. I have three tables:

- brokers (PK: brokerId)
- markets (PK: marketId)
- brokerMarkets (PK: brokerId, marketId), MinIncrement column goes in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would create a third entity:

```
public class BrokerMarketRelationship
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Broker Broker { get; set; }
    public Market Market { get; set; }
    public int MinIncrement { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you explain why you chose that solution over others like say inheritance or a list of brokers in the market object and a list of markets in the broker object?

Comment: You can have a many-to-many relationship like you say, with a collection on both sides, but you won't be able to easily cater for the MinIncrement property. I'm not sure what you have in mind using 'inheritance'. If MinIncrement is definately a property of the relationship between Brokers and Markets, then you should give the relationship its own entity. That's how I do it anyway. Many-to-many can actually be a bit annoying in NHibernate. By giving the relationship its own entity you break the many-to-many into two one-to-many relationships instead, which personally I find makes life easier.

Comment: I'm aware in my example that you lose the ability to uniquely enforce the Broker/Market combination in your DB using a primary key. If you're deseparate you can add a seperate unique constraint, or you can try and implement a composite key instead of using the surrogate ID column on the Relationship entity. The former could impact on performance but might be fine, depending on your scenario. The latter is possible in NHibernate but personally I find it problematic to work with. Depending on the scenario I might forgo enforcing uniqueness at the database level.