# How to configure nHibernate for many-many mapping with xml files?

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

I've been struggling with this for a while see my previous question [How to configure nHibernate for many-many mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766096/how-to-configure-nhibernate-for-many-many-mapping)

I have recreated my project from scratch in an attempt to solve it. I have two classes `Broker` and `Instrument` and I have a property unique to a `Broker` and an `Instrument` called `MinIncrement` that I need to store in my many-many mapping table in the database. I created a third class called `BrokerInstrument` to model this extra information. Here is the code for my classes:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Version {get; private set;}
}

public class Broker : Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<BrokerInstrument> BrokerInstruments { get; set; }
}

public class Instrument : Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get;  set; }
    public virtual string Name { get;  set; }
    public virtual string Symbol {get;  set;}
    public virtual ISet<BrokerInstrument> BrokerInstruments { get; set; }

}

public class BrokerInstrument : Entity
{
    public virtual Broker Broker { get; set; }
    public virtual Instrument Instrument { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal MinIncrement { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        var t = obj as BrokerInstrument;
        if (t == null)
            return false;

        if ((Instrument == t.Instrument) && (Broker == t.Broker))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Broker.Name + "|" + Instrument.Symbol).GetHashCode();            
    }
}
```

My mapping files look like this:
Broker.hbm.xml

```
  <class name="MooDB.Domain.Broker,MooDB" table="brokers">
    <id name="Id" column="brokerId" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <version name="Version" column="version" type="integer" unsaved-value="0" />
    <property name="Name" column="`name`" type="String" length="50" not-null="true" />
    <property name="IsActive" column="isActive" type="bool" not-null="true" />
    <property name="IsDefault" column="isDefault" type="bool" not-null="true" />
  </class>
```

Instrument.hbm.xml

```
  <class name="MooDB.Domain.Instrument,MooDB"  table="instruments">
    <id name="Id" column="instrumentId" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <version name="Version" column="version" type="integer" unsaved-value="0"/>
    <property name="Symbol" column="symbol" type="string" length="10" not-null="false"/>
    <property name="Name" column="`name`" type="string" length="30" not-null="false"/>
  </class>
```

And the mapping file I'm struggling with:
BrokerInstrument.hbm.xml

```
  <class name="MooDB.Domain.BrokerInstrument,MooDB"  table="brokerInstruments">
    <composite-id name="BrokerInstrumentIdentifier" class="BrokerInstrument" >
      <key-many-to-one class="Broker" column="brokerId" name="Id" />
      <key-many-to-one class="Instrument" column="instrumentId" name="Id" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="MinIncrement" column="minIncrement" type="decimal" not-null="true" />
  </class>
```

I'm pretty sure the elements enclosed within `composite-id` tags are wrong. Do you know what should go in there? Also, does my class design look right to support this model?

**UPDATE 1**

In response to Cole's reply. I have made the change suggested and I now get this error:

> Test 'Test.Test.CanAddBrokerInstrument' failed: TestFixtureSetUp
>   failed in Test
>
> TestFixture failed: NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException : Could not
>   find a getter for property 'BrokerInstrumentIdentifier' in class
>   'MooDB.Domain.BrokerInstrument'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this isn't really an M:N relationship. it's a M:1 & 1:N relationships between 3 entities. From simplicity of modeling and queries I would assign an Id to BrokerInstrument and remove the need for a composite key all together.

anytime you can avoid composite you should. this type of mapping is for legacy databases.

Comment: I'm inclined to disagree with you Jason, especially the last line of your answer. A surrogate key only wastes disk space, increases page size, and therefore impacts performance. It seems inelegant to have to fudge the database design to get the ORM tool to do what I need. Composite primary keys in many-many relationships is good database design and not "legacy" as you put it.

Comment: space and performance are not valid arguments to avoid non-composite PK's with today's technology.

Comment: I did get it working with your suggestion, although it still "feels" wrong. I'm sure I'll get over it.

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute within your `key-many-to-one` should be the property name of your object within your `BrokerInstrument` class.

```
<key-many-to-one class="Broker" column="brokerId" name="Broker" />
<key-many-to-one class="Instrument" column="instrumentId" name="Instrument" />
```

#### Edit:

```
<class name="MooDB.Domain.BrokerInstrument,MooDB"  table="brokerInstruments">
    <composite-id>
      <key-many-to-one class="Broker" column="brokerId" name="Broker" />
      <key-many-to-one class="Instrument" column="instrumentId" name="Instrument" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="MinIncrement" column="minIncrement" type="decimal" not-null="true" />
</class>
```

Comment: Cole I updated my question, because there is a further problem.

Comment: @MarkAllison Take out all those attributes in your `composite-id` tag.

Comment: I'm confused. You are suggesting I remove the lines that you posted in your answer? If I do that I get this error: "XML validation error: The element 'composite-id' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has incomplete content."

Comment: @MarkAllison  No that is not what I'm suggesting.  Take a look at my edit.